# HG abort on permitted file?

Tags: mercurial

I keep getting this error with HG (Mercurial), it seems like it's having a problem with the file, but i have permissions on the file, so i'm not sure why it's returning an error:

```
me@server:/repo$ hg up -v
resolving manifests
getting __init__.py
abort: Operation not permitted: /repo/__init__.py.orig

me@server:/repo$ ls -l /repo/__init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 3022 2012-03-22 14:13 /repo/__init__.py

me@server:/repo$ ls -ld /repo/
-rwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 2012-03-22 13:23 /repo/
```

here is another sample:

```
me@server:/repo$ ls -l /repo/modular.py.orig 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 34188 2012-03-29 12:50 /repo/modular.py.orig

me@server:/repo$ ls -l /repo/ -d
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 2012-03-29 12:50 /repo/
```

Any ideas how i can prevent this in the future?

Comment: I updated to include the folder's permissions, and yes i'm a member of  the www-data group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's saying it's unable to create the file `/repo/__init__.py.orig`.  Check these permissions:

```
ls -l /repo/__init__.py.orig
```

and

```
ls -l /repo/
```

You need write access for both of those for user 'me'

Comment: I think you are right, but the problem is that the file is already there. So it can't create it because it's already there. I think my problem is coming from merging/update or whatever causes .orig files to appear.

Comment: .orig files come from 'revert' which I wouldn't expect to come into play here.  Regardless you can move it aside and try again.

Comment: Yep that seems to have worked. I guess i'm going to be more careful with those, thank you!